# Did Samson drink wine?

Tags: bible

Did Samson drink wine?
Nazirite vow restricted one from drinking wine.

Is there evidence in the bible that Samson violated the terms of a Nazirite vow?

Comment: Would you like to tell us 1) why was Samson not supposed to drink wine ? and 2)  when is it recorded that he did actually drink wine ? There is absolutely no research or background information to your question at all.This question is very lacking in detail.

Comment: - Nigel J // The question clearly relates to the laws of Nazarites in comparison to Samson's life choices in the book of Judges.

Answer (score 2):

Technically - In Shoftim (Judges) 13:3-7, we learn the Angel of YHVH (מַלְאַ֨ךְ יְהֹוַ֜ה) and the Wife (הָאִשָּׁ֗ה) of Manoah (מָנ֑וֹחַ) make the Nazirite vow for Manoah's son Samson (Shimeshon , שִׁמְשׁוֹן) to hopefully become a Nezir (נְזִיר) . * Samson never makes a Nazirite (נָּזִ֗יר) vow. Samson prays and makes a request after he is humbled, losing his hair and sight.

- Shimshon's Prayer in [Shoftim (Judges) 16:28]:
  "And Samson called to the Lord and said, "God YHVH, remember me and strengthen me now, only this once my Lord YHVH, that I may be avenged the vengeance for one of my two eyes from the Philistines."

( וַיִּקְרָ֥א שִׁמְשׁ֛וֹן אֶל־יְהֹוָ֖ה וַיֹּאמַ֑ר אֲדֹנָ֣י יֱהֹוִֹ֡ה זָכְרֵ֣נִי נָא֩ וְחַזְּקֵ֨נִי נָ֜א אַ֣ךְ הַפַּ֚עַם הַזֶּה֙ הָאֱלֹהִ֔ים וְאִנָּקְמָ֧ה נְקַם־אַחַ֛ת מִשְּׁתֵ֥י עֵינַ֖י מִפְּלִשְׁתִּֽים)

Samson never vows to abstain from wine (Yayin, יַ֣יִן), but His mother is told to abstain from Yayin during her pregnancy. * Children do not always become what their parents want them to become. Regarding the Nazirite vow in Bamidbar (Numbers) 6:2-3, a mother cannot make a Nazirite vow for her son. The vow must be made by a Yisraelite man or woman who sets themself apart to become holy for God.

Comment: Interesting suggestion that Samson never made the vow of the Nazarite. It certainly appears that Samson broke many of the rules that Nazarites had to keep, yet the Lord blessed him. https://www.gotquestions.org/life-Samson.html